# Rails5 / strong parameters / json columns with 'dynamic' keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, jsonb

Googling around, found a hell of a lot of potentials solutions to handle it correctly, ended up with the following, which work

```
    def item_params
      load_params = params.require(:item).permit(
        :title,
        :content
      )
      load_params[:meta] = params[:item][:meta] if params[:item][:meta]
      load_params.permit!
    end
```

Using such payloads (looking at the console) :

```
{
  "item" => {
    "title"=>"abc",
    "meta"=>{
      "fontcolor"=>"xyz",
    }
  }
}
```

The logs still shows that the field is unpermitted :

```
Unpermitted parameter: :meta
```

Not blocking, it does passes those parameters and saves correctly,  even if warned about.

Not using serialize or any serializers on the concerned column, as it works as expected without it (talking to a large amount of posts talking about json column and serializing, does not seems as required now as it seemed to be once)

This solution does not work on my side, same warning but does the meta param is blocked :

```
def item_params
  meta_keys = params[:item][:meta].keys
  params.require(:item).permit(:title, meta: meta_keys)
end
```

As this is seem a bit random, i feel quite uncomfortable taking a final decision about what to use and how to use it; so thx a lot  if any confident advices

Comment: Can you also share `sample data` that you are posting ?

Comment: @skam added a relevant example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of **Strong Parameters** is not allowing arbitrary parameters. I would recommend that try and whitelist all the keys you want to allow and only allow those.

But to answer your question, if you want to allow dynamic keys the following should do it without logging `Unpermitted parameter:`

```
def item_params
  meta_keys = params.require(:item).fetch(:meta, {}).keys
  params.require(:item).permit(:title,:meta => meta_keys)
end
```

Comment: Thks. Even years after :) In case I have a jsonb column -  an array of hashes with dynamic keys -  say array = [{a:1,b:2},{a:1,c:3}], then following you, I can do (:array,[]).map(&:keys).flatten.uniq to get the keys and allow strong params. Great!